# Recaptcha not working on Umbraco Contour 3.0.21

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, umbraco, recaptcha, contour

Versions Umbraco: 6.2.1, Contour: 3.0.21 ... using MVC mode

ReCaptcha field not working. Form submitting without validating captcha.

I have tried with setting mandatory, both on and off in settings... both have no effect.

validate works for all other fields, but if a value is in recaptcha field or not, the form still submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
            var recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Captcha answer cannot be empty.");

                return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
            }

            var recaptchaResult = recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponse();

            if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect captcha answer.");
            }
```

and these references:

using Recaptcha.Web;

using Recaptcha.Web.Mvc;